# QGIS CSV file sorts low numbers as high

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv

So I have numbers that range from 5 to above 50, and when I sort these from least to greatest, the numbers less than 10 are treated as higher than anything else.  It also does the same when I try to symbolize by category, and treats the less than 10 numbers as higher than the actual higher integers.  I am a total noob an have no idea what I am doing in QGIS or how to begin to solve this problem.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: are you sure that Qgis is seeing the number as numbers, and not as Text?

Comment: That is, is the field a numerical field or a text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make qgis know the data types in csv you can use a csvt file http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/